# Is there a way to resize a module, inside a process, or extend one to be longer in memory?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dll

I am curious to know if it is possible to extend a process module, like a dll, to be larger.

As an example, I inject test.dll into test.exe, I make test.dll + 0x1000 bytes larger, these new bytes now have PAGE_EXECUTE privileges and I can modify them however I like.

I want to be able to do this only after injecting the dll, not by adding fake code to the dll to overwrite, as I will likely have no control over the execution of the actual test subject.

I have already tried to use VirtualAlloc on the end of the dll's sections to increase its size, but it hasn't worked, I usually get ERROR_BAD_ADDRESS, I made sure to verify the process had enough space after the dll to allocate to and commit to.

```
uint64_t module_contents = (uint64_t)GetModuleHandleA(NULL);

IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dos_header = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)module_contents;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64* nt_header = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)(module_contents + dos_header->e_lfanew);
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* section = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*)(nt_header + 1);

for (unsigned short i = 0; i < nt_header->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
    if (!section->SizeOfRawData && section->Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE) {
        char name[8];
        memcpy(name, section->Name, sizeof(name));

        if (std::string(name).find("text") == std::string::npos) {
            //std::cout << name << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    section++;
}

std::cout << VirtualAlloc((void*)(module_contents + section->VirtualAddress + section->Misc.PhysicalAddress), 0x1000, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE) << std::endl;
```

The expected result of this is to fill in and commit to the empty space after the module's sections, which I verify has not been committed to both by the cout & with Cheat Engine to look at the memory region. The result I get is an error message of 0x1E7, or ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS. I have gotten other error messages like ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, when using a smaller size like 0x1.

Any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: Why not use VirtualAlloc with an unspecified address, so that the OS will allocate/reserve memory somewhere where it can, then you can write the instructions to that memory and use VirtualProtect to give that memory the execute privilege. Afterwards, you can jump to that memory from the injected DLL.

Comment: I need it right after the module, literally to extend its memory. which is why i asked the question like this

Comment: According to the [documentation on the VirtualAlloc function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc), the requested address is automatically rounded down to the nearest page boundary. Is the address you are passing to VirtualAlloc on such a page boundary? If not, then it might be rounded down to the address of a page that has already been allocated for the injected DLL, which causes VirtualAlloc to fail (because the requested address is already allocated).

Comment: Another issue could be that if you want to extend a section that is not the last section (it seems you want to extend the .text section), there may be no room in the process's virtual address space for a whole page of memory (normally 4096 bytes) to be allocated before the next section. Also, I'm not sure if every section has its own separate memory allocation or if there is one memory allocation for the whole DLL. In the latter case, it would certainly not be possible to extend any section that is not the last section.

Comment: Why are you rejecting the solution? If you want your module to be a particular size, make it that size.

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can do with this. I read up on a person using undocumented VAD kernel methods to extend a process's size dynamically and I wanted to know if there was a way to do that without needing such extra measures. Thank you, seriously a lot of help.